# How to get a specific field from json object by key:value?

Tags: c#, object, elixir-jason

I'm trying to save my data using json. I don't know how to get specific object group from a set of json objects.

```
[
{
  "dateinformation": "2021-10-05:23:01",
  "id": 1,
  "MoveCount": 3,
  "StartPoint": 2322,
  "TotalDist": 2331,
  "SafeDist": 21332,
  "Feed": 2332,
  "EndPoint":23245,
  "Count":1221,

},
{

  "dateinformation": "2021-10-05:26:01",
  "id": 2,
  "MoveCount": 3,     
  "StartPoint": 2322,
  "TotalDist": 2331,
  "SafeDist": 21332,
  "Feed": 2332,
  "EndPoint":23245,
  "Count":1221,
},
{

  "dateinformation": "2021-10-55:03:01",
  "id": 3,
  "MoveCount": 3,
  "StartPoint": 2322,
  "TotalDist": 2331,
  "SafeDist": 21332,
  "Feed": 2332,
  "EndPoint":23245,
  "Count":1221,

}]
```

is it possible to get/delete a specific object from a bundle of json object by its "id" value?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please **edit** your question to include more information.
 i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). hint: the _first_ step in "doing something with json" is **always**: deserialise it into the correct data structure.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and advice. I'll try to make a good question next time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do like that

**NameSpace will include:**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

Here you can replace your id by specificId

```
 List<Root> myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(myJsonResponse); // myJsonResponse is My Source Json
        int specificId = 123; // my dynamic
        var specficObject = myDeserializedClass.Where(x => x.id == specificId);
```

**Class for Deserialize your JSON response:**

```
     public class Root
        {
            public string dateinformation { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
            public int MoveCount { get; set; }
            public int StartPoint { get; set; }
            public int TotalDist { get; set; }
            public int SafeDist { get; set; }
            public int Feed { get; set; }
            public int EndPoint { get; set; }
            public int Count { get; set; }
        }
```

Also, I have noticed your JSON last column comma in last that should not be like that "Count" : 1221,

Comment: Thank you.!!! This is exactly what I wanted to implement in my project!!.

Comment: Welcome Glad to hear that! Kindly like my answer if possible that will help me to keep motivated Thanks